# Store a filename in a variable minus the extension

Tags: bash, scripts

File: test.zip

Bash script

```
while read filename; do
zip_file=${filename}
# do stuff    
done;
```

Value stored in variable = "test"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bash` [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```bsh
zip_file="${filename}"
new_name="${zip_file%.*}"
```

- `new_name` will contain the name `test` if the `zip_file` has `test.zip`
- If the `zip_file` has `test.foo.zip`, `new_name` will have `test.foo`, if you want only `test` out of `test.foo.zip` use:

  ```
  new_name="${zip_file%%.*}"
  ```

Comment: This seems to include part of the path. I just want the file name. eg NOT `./Somefolder/Somefolder/FilenameminusExtn` but `FilenameminusExtn`

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle With due respect why would you give the filename as `test.zip`, why don't you include the path or mention that there would be path before the file name? Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/627678/edit) and add some examples (be precise) and your desired output (be precise)..

Comment: I think you just need $(basename "${zip_file}") to get what I want.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle no, you would need `$(basename "${zipfile}" .zip)` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

heemayl is still right: example:

```
full_path=/foo/bar/baz.zip
file_name="${full_path##*/}"
name="${file_name%.*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
zip_file="$(<<< "${filename}" sed -r 's/^(.*)\..*/\1/')"
```

- `zip_file="$( [...] )"`: assigns the `stdout` of an invoked subshell to the variable `zip_file` as a string
- `<<< "${filename}" [...]`: redirects the content of the variable `${filename}` to the invoked subshell's `stdin` as a string
- `sed -r 's/^(.*)\./\1/'`: edits the content of the invoked subshell's `stdin` using extended regular expressions, by matching the whole string and replacing it with the substring matching every character from the start until the last dot

**Edit**: Having seen your comment to heemayl's answer, to replace with the substring matching every character from the last slash to the last dot:

```
zip_file="$(<<< "${filename}" sed -r 's/^.*\/(.*)\..*/\1/')"
```